# Splunk bucket name conversion to epoch to human script

Tags: splunk, epoch

I'm facing the following issue: I have some frozen bucket in a Splunk enviroment that are saved in epoch format. More specifically the template is:

```
db_1181756465_1162600547_1001
```

that, if converted, return to me the end date, which is in the first number, and the start one, that is in the second one. So, it means that, base on my example:

```
1181756465 = Wednesday 13 June 2007 17:41:05
1162600547 = Saturday 4 November 2006 00:35:47
```

Now, ho to convert in human is clear for me, also because if not i coudn't put the translation here. My problem is that I have file full of bucket name that must be converted, with hunderds of entry; so, I'm asking if there is a script or other way to authomatize this conversion and print the output in a file. The idea is to have the final oputput with somehting like that:

```
db_1181756465_1162600547_1001 = Wednesday 13 June 2007 17:41:05 - Saturday 4 November 2006 00:35:47
```

Comment: out of curiosity ... why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Splunk to view these values. They are outputted from the `dbinspect` command which provides startEpoch & endEpoch times for the frozen bucket

```
| dbinspect index=* state=frozen
| eval startDate=strftime(startEpoch,"%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
| eval endDate=strftime(endEpoch,"%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
| fields index, path, startDate, endDate
```

*listing example using hot buckets since I don't have frozen in this test system*
[image]

If you just have the list of folder names you can upload it to a Splunk instance as CSV and do some processing to extract startDate & endDate

```
| makeresults
| eval frozenbucket="db_1181756465_1162600547_1001"
| eval temp=split(frozenbucket,"_") 
| eval sDate=mvindex(temp,2)
| eval eDate=mvindex(temp,1)
| eval startDate=strftime(sDate,"%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
| eval endDate=strftime(eDate,"%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
| fields frozenbucket,startDate,endDate
| fields - _time
```